# NullPointerException in GWT using Objectify

Tags: java, gwt, objectify

I am using Objectify for my GWT(Java) application.

I am getting the error (Stack Trace given below).

Can you suggest what is the cause of this exception?

I am using Objectify `(V 4 - objectify-4.0b1.jar).`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.CacheControlImpl.getExpirySeconds(CacheControlImpl.java:25)
at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.EntityMemcache.getAll(EntityMemcache.java:207)
at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService.get(CachingAsyncDatastoreService.java:253)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine$Round.fetchPending(LoadEngine.java:172)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine$Round.execute(LoadEngine.java:118)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine.execute(LoadEngine.java:258)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.LoadContext.done(LoadContext.java:53)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine$Round$2.postExecuteHook(LoadEngine.java:147)
at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:33)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine$Round$1.nowUncached(LoadEngine.java:75)
at com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache.now(ResultCache.java:30)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ref.StdRef.get(StdRef.java:57)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.QueryImpl$3.translate(QueryImpl.java:382)
at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.cmd.QueryImpl$3.translate(QueryImpl.java:379)
at com.googlecode.objectify.util.TranslatingQueryResultIterable$1.translate(TranslatingQueryResultIterable.java:31)
at com.googlecode.objectify.util.TranslatingIterator.next(TranslatingIterator.java:35)
at com.l3.rnlgpc.server.DAO.CaseDAO.getCases(CaseDAO.java:189)
at com.l3.rnlgpc.server.manager.CaseManager.getCases(CaseManager.java:52)
at com.l3.rnlgpc.server.manager.ExportManager.export(ExportManager.java:49)
at com.l3.rnlgpc.server.servlet.export.ExportCaseToCSV.doGet(ExportCaseToCSV.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:59)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:57)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:439)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:483)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:490)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:777)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:754)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:345)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:337)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:487)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Did you register your model?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have registered my Model and this issue doesn't come always. Also this issue is only coming on GAE and never on my dev machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug on objectfy, based in this [link](https://groups.google.com/group/objectify-appengine/tree/browse_frm/thread/b3c5caee7b78dfc0/59f656f010797193?hide_quotes=no).

> This is a bug - it will be fixed soon.  Sorry about that.  Jeff

To solve that you need to register the model, as detailed here

> Using Objectify 4, I have written this line of code :
>
> MyModel model =
> ofy.load().type(MyModel.class).id(42).get();
>
> And simply forgot to
> register MyModel with
>
> ObjectifyService.register(MyModel.class);
> Objectify 3 used to throw an exception like "Class MyModel has not
> been  registered" or something like that but Objectify 4 throws a
> NullPointerException.

Comment: I have registered the Model classes being used in the class. I am now trying by adding all model classes present in my project considering they might be indirectly getting referenced.

Comment: ok, yes you need to have all the classes registered... let me know if it works.

Comment: After registering all Model in application, I have so far not seen this exception. Thanks.